# Friendships in CakePHP 2.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm having trouble setting up friendships with CakePHP 2.

I have two database tables: **users** and **friends**. My users table has the following columns:

- id
- email
- password

And my friends table has the following columns:

- id
- user_id
- friend_id
- approved

I have friends set up as a hasAndBelongsToMany relationship in my Users model:

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel {
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Friends' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'joinTable' => 'friends',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'friend_id',
            'unique' => true
        )
    );
}
```

Now, when I try and retrieve friends for a user, it only lists friendships that the specified user initiated, i.e. where `user_id` is equal to the user ID; it doesn't show me friends where the other person may have initiated the request (i.e. where the current user's ID is in the `friend_id` column).

How can I fetch friends, so records where either the `user_id` or `friend_id` column is equal to a particular ID?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you understand how HABTM works. Read [this part of the book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm). You will need a friends_users table in addition to the tables you have for the relationship to work. I think if you were going to set it up this way, you'd need to define a Friendship as having and belonging to many Users.

However, I question whether with your current setup you want a HABTM relationship. It seems like a user *hasMany* friends, and that's it. Look into using that relationship, and it'll give you the relevant ID as you expect it to. Don't forget to define Friend *belongsTo* User.

---

Here beings my canonical Cake 2.0 Friendship tutorial. I downloaded cakePHP 2.1 so I had a fresh start. I first changed my security salt and cipher, then added my database connection. Then I structured my database as follows:

**Database**:

`users` table:

```
id         | int(11)
created    | datetime
username   | varchar(255)
```

`friendships` table:

```
id         | int(11)
user_from  | varchar(255)
user_to    | varchar(255)
created    | datetime
status     | varchar(50)
```

Obviously, your users table can/will have more stuff, but this is the minimum I needed.

**Models**:

Okay this is the tricky part. Here are the relationship I defined in my User model.

```
class User extends AppModel {
/* Other code if you have it */
        var $hasMany = array(
          'FriendFrom'=>array(
             'className'=>'Friendship',
             'foreignKey'=>'user_from'
          ),
          'FriendTo'=>array(
             'className'=>'Friendship',
             'foreignKey'=>'user_to'
          )
       );
       var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
          'UserFriendship' => array(
              'className' => 'User',
              'joinTable' => 'friendships',
              'foreignKey' => 'user_from',
              'associationForeignKey' => 'user_to'
            )
       );
/* Again, other code */
}
```

Here is my Friendship model:

```
class Friendship extends AppModel {
/* Other code if you have it */
    var $belongsTo = array(
      'UserFrom'=>array(
         'className'=>'User',
         'foreignKey'=>'user_from'
      ),
      'UserTo'=>array(
         'className'=>'User',
         'foreignKey'=>'user_to'
      )
   );
/* Again, other code */
}
```

*Note on models*: The friendship model belongs to 2 users. The user model has 3 associations. The two hasMany relationships in the User Model are both aliases for the accessing the Friendship model's data, so we can use `$this->User->FriendTo` or `$this->User->FriendFrom` from controllers to get to the Friendship model. I at first called these UserFrom and UserTo, mirroring the setup of the Friendship model, but Cake threw a hissyfit about similarities, so I had to make them more distinct.

**Controllers and Views**:
I baked controllers and views using the bake utility. I then created two users (Daniel and Martin) and created a new friendship from Daniel to Martin with a status of `requested`. I then updated the friendship status to `confirmed`.

I created the following viewless custom user action to demonstrate data retrieval about a friendship from the UsersController:

```
public function test() {
  $data = $this->User->FriendFrom->find('all', 
    array(
      'conditions'=>array('user_from'=>1), 
      'contain'=>array('UserTo')
    )
  );
  die(debug($data));
}
```

This find uses the hasMany relationship of the UserModel to access the Friendship model and get the related `user_from` and `user_to` data for the relationships where the user with the id of 1 initiated the relationships.

**Your specific find**:

Martin, the find you're looking for is super simple under this system, and while you could do it differently, you'd always be dealing with a similar method, simply as long as there are always two sides to a relationship. All you have to do is get a list of relationships where your user ID is either user1 or user2 (in my case, just so I know who initiated the relationship, I have them stored as user_to and user_from- I think this is what intimidated you). Then I iterate through the whole array, selecting the relevant friend data based on whether I am user1 or 2 in that given array. It's a really simple method, and I just put it in my user Model. Change the die(debug()); to `return $friendslist` to be able to call it from your controller and get an array back.

```
public function getFriends($idToFind) {
  $data = $this->FriendFrom->find('all', 
    array(
      'conditions'=>array(
        'OR'=> array(
            array('user_to'=> $idToFind),
            array('user_from'=> $idToFind)
        )
        )
    )
  );
  $friendslist = array();
  foreach ($data as $i) {
    if ($i['FriendFrom']['user_from'] == $idToFind){
        $friendslist[] = $i['UserTo'];
    }
    elseif ($i['FriendFrom']['user_to'] == $idToFind){
        $friendslist[] = $i['UserFrom'];
    }
  }

  die(debug($friendslist));
}
```

Comment: Why? The relationship data exists in the `friends` table?

Comment: Yeah, looking more at your question, I really think you want to be using a HasMany relationship instead of HABTM.

Comment: Is the friend a user as well? In that case you have a HABTM relationship from user to user, in which case you need a friends table as swiecki stated

Comment: So how would I fetch records where either `user_id` or `friend_id` is a particular ID?

Comment: If User hasmany Friends then you can do a find on the Friend model as such assuming you can get the current user's id from say, the Auth component: `$myFriends= $this->Friend->find('all',array('conditions' => array('Friend.user_id' => $thisUserId)));`. This searches the friends table for friends where the related user id is the id you pass in.

Comment: Will this fetch users who initiated the request? I don't think it will; only friends that I've requested to be friends with (presuming I'm passing my own user ID).

Comment: That's correct. While you could store a friend_id along with the record and do an 'OR' condition to search for requests in both directions, this example highlights the reason why it is awkward to represent a friend relationship as a 1 way relationship. If you take the User HABTM Friendship approach, then you can simply look up friendships associated with a given user, and then get a list of all users (and their data as well) associated with that friendship.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm still having trouble getting this work. Could someone actually post an answer with example code rather than a comment…?

Comment: Martin, sorry for not being clear. I will amend my answer to be a complete with actual code this afternoon, using the user habtm friendship approach.

Comment: Ok Martin, above should be everything you need to get started. If cake complains about names being similar, you can alter the alias name in the Model files.

Comment: Hi swiecki. Thanks for taking the time to update your answer, but I'm still not getting the desired results. The above gives me users I've requested to be friends with, but not those who've requested to be friends with me. I literally just want a list of friends, like say Facebook.

Comment: Martin, the find you want to do is actually really simple given this system. I have updated my answer above...

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer, swiecki. However, I'm getting the following error with your `getFriends()` action: `Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'first_name' in field list is ambiguous`.