# User has many Users relationship, The CakePHP Way

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a table

```
Users:
id|name|surname
```

Now I need to relate users to each other such that each **User** has many **Users** (by many users I actually mean friends e.g facebook friends).

Following CakePHP conventions one would probably end up with a wierd tables like this:

```
Users
id|name|surname

UserUsers
id|user_id|user_id
```

What is the best way to modify my structure to achieve this. Please note this might have been asked before BUT as far as I have searched , it has not been asked specifically for CakePHP 3.X putting into consideration Cakephp conventions and all.

Comment: The join table name supposed to be UsersUsers, and you can not have 2 user_id filed in the same database table. I would add a second model named Friends which is connected to the Users table, and have a UsersFriends join model.

Comment: The version of CakePHP you are using, or even using CakePHP at all, has no bearing on the answer. That's a bit like asking for driving directions from A to B **specifically for blue cars**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Friendships in CakePHP 2.x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277974/friendships-in-cakephp-2-x) (First found duplicate, if it doesn't solve your question please search for "friendship schema" or similar)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can define a relationship like this in your UsersTable in cake 3:

```
$this->belongsTo('Users', [
            'className'  => 'Users',
            'foreignKey' => 'facebook_user_id',
            'joinType'   => 'LEFT'
        ]);
```

You will have to define a facebook_user_id and set it up as a foreign key to your id.